# Text doesn't want to align in center?

Tags: css

I got this code but the "test" text doesn't want to align in center:

```
.mainContent {
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
    color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can see it live at: http://vizz.tv/

Comment: please include your HTML too

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that, if you're just trying to center your header than do this.

```
.wrap {
    width: 940px;
}
h2 { 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3bM9K/)

Comment: Hmm, I added that but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Or try:

```
h2 {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Added that but it didn't help :/